# Streaming live video in HTML5 and with HLS

Tags: javascript, html, http-live-streaming

I wish to stream live video [in my https website](https://www.eoy.ee/metsis/muu) from [this http site.](http://tv.eenet.ee/metsis.html)

Added reference of hls.min.js into my template. Copy-pasted their code:

```
<video id="video" width="320" height="240" controls autoplay 
class="videoCentered"></video>
<script>
if(Hls.isSupported()) {
var video = document.getElementById('video');
var hls = new Hls();
hls.loadSource('/hls/metsis.m3u8');
hls.attachMedia(video);
hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED,function() {
  video.play();
});
}
</script>
```

into my template, but the player doesn't start to stream.
browser console says:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Hls is not defined

Where exactly is reference error? Here?

```
hls.loadSource('/hls/metsis.m3u8');
```

Answer (score 4):

correct working code:

```
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hls.js@latest"></script>
 <video id="video" width="100%" height="380" controls autoplay 
class="videoCentered"></video>
<script>
if(Hls.isSupported()) {
var video = document.getElementById('video');
var hls = new Hls();
hls.loadSource('http://tv.eenet.ee/hls/metsis.m3u8');
hls.attachMedia(video);
hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED,function() {
  video.play();
});
}
</script>
```

but browser blocks it, because `the content must be served over https` if my page is loaded over https.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error as you are trying to access Hls without importing it. Please import it using the following way

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hls.js@latest"></script>
```

A more detailed example can be seen at Getting Started section of [HLS documentation](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/)

Also, Add the correct reference

```
hls.loadSource('https://video-dev.github.io/streams/x36xhzz/x36xhzz.m3u8');
```

Comment: but i have imported it (sroll down in source view): 
<script src="https://www.eoy.ee/metsis/js/hls.min.js"></script>

Comment: changed to latest as you suggested, didn't help. i'm afraid that this `hls.loadSource('/hls/metsis.m3u8');` is uncorrect reference...

Comment: clear. i think i got the correct reference, but, it doesn't stream anyway: `The page at 'https://www.eoy.ee/metsis/muu' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://tv.eenet.ee/hls/metsis.m3u8'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

Answer (score 0):

You need a **crossorigin** attribute to handle insecure urls...

```
crossOrigin="anonymous"
```

And a **muted** attribute so that autoplay will function...

```
muted
```

For HLS standard/compatibility I would also add a **type** attribute...

```
type="application/x-mpegURL"
```

Putting it all together the HTML player becomes...

```
<video id="video" type="application/x-mpegURL" crossOrigin="anonymous" class="videoCentered" width="100%" height="380" muted controls autoplay></video>
```